# Как поменять фон в Vs Code?

Tags: изображения, visual-studio-code

Всем привет. Как поставить свою картинку в VS code на фон? Может быть есть какое нибудь полезное расширение?

Comment: а пробовали в расширениях просто поискать по слову background? Их там "тысячи".

Comment: искал, но все они не работают, или работают криво(если бы я бы нашел нормальное расширение очевидно я бы не задавал здесь вопрос:) )

Comment: с формулировки вопроса это не очевидно. Я посмотрел на них, они какие то действительно странные. Но я не знаю, зачем такое может понадобится в обычной разработке. Так, для записи "мегакулхацкерного видео" - возможно. В любом случае, можно взять и свое написать. И оно будет таким как нужно и другие скажут спасибо